# Get all scripts from external website

Tags: php, javascript, wget, bookmarklet

I have a some code here and I with this code render external page (similar to iframe) but I got a source code. But when I start my code all is good but one window is showing there and I can't to close his to see contents. Here is the code:
Code:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;

echo $data;

?>
```

and this generate a good HTML page but to close window I need also to get all scripts with this bookmarklet

```
javascript: (function(){
    s = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT');
    tx = '';
    sr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        with (s.item(i)) {
            t = text;
            if (t) {
                tx += t;
            }
            else {
                sr.push(src)
            };
                    }
    };
    with (window.open()) {
        document.write('<textarea%20id="t">' + (sr.join("\n")) + "\n\n-----\n\n" + tx + '</textarea><script%20src="http://jsbeautifier.org/beautify.js"></script><script>with(document.getElementById("t")){value=js_beautify(value);with(style){width="99%";height="99%";borderStyle="none";}};</script>');
        document.close();
    }
})();
```

But how can I implement this in my code above? Here is the demo of first (only php code) http://www.pluspon.com/get1.php or maybe to do this with some wget?

Comment: Is there any way to I close that window???

Comment: or to javascript work on my site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hack way : if you just want to get rid of the window, you just need to add css that hide that window element.

```
<style>
#home_banner_campaign_wrapper,#active_banner_wrap {display:none;}
</style>
```

by, umm..perhaps like this :

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$style = '<style>#home_banner_campaign_wrapper,#active_banner_wrap {display:none;}</style>';

//insert the style just before the closing head tag
$data = str_replace('</head>', $style.'</head>', $data);
$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;

echo $data;
?>
```

well pardon me if this way is too stupid..

Comment: It, usefull for this site but when I change URL to groupon example there is again the window

Comment: do you use firebug or something similar to inspect the html? i believe the id of the popup-window is different. give the sample url that you grab groupon content

Comment: I dont know how to just close that window nothing else:(