# Execute JavaScript files into my code from external sites

Tags: javascript, php, file, executable

I have this code to show me some web page into my domain (in my page):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;

echo $data;

?>
```

and all is fine but when I try to close something or do something it doesn't work because there are no JS files on my server and in the head section is /script/file.js can't execute. How to solve this problem and how to allow this code to execute into source code. Is there any answer?

You can see demo [www.pluspon.com/get1.php](http://www.pluspon.com/get1.php) and you will see that all is good but I can't close the div popup window because JS files don't work. If you click on ('X') to close, you see that it doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to figure out which network requests didn't work and why...

Comment: I suggest using firebug / chrome developer tools / IE developer tools. Check which resources can't be loaded

Comment: yes, but errors you can see also in Chrome console

Comment: I cant loaded all files in head section which I need to work on page

Comment: I dont know why I cant close that window to see content of page

Comment: is this also you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504757/get-all-scripts-from-external-website ?

Comment: No, its no my question but I'm get the code from there and do some modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is generating invalid html; you are adding a `head` section, closing it and then add another one from the original site.

What you need to do, is use the whole original site and insert the `base` tag in the original `head` section.

Comment: I'm do this: $url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data1 = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" />';

$data = str_replace ('<head>',$data1,$data); but again is the same, CANT CLOSE WINDOW POPUP

Comment: also IT cant be a problem becouse there is a title from HEAD section from original site

Comment: HOW I CAN SOLVE THIS PROBLEM!!??

Comment: please HELP, I'm trying to do that 4days

Comment: @ddd The `head` problem seems solved now, but some javascript will probably not run because of the google error message; `This web site needs a different Google Maps API key.`

Comment: @ddd if there are codes required that are related to the original domain, there's not much you can do.